# Removing sublists of Lists based on Len of sublists

Tags: python, list

I started learning python recently and I need your help. I have a list of Lists and I need to remove the lists that have a len inferior to some number.

I've checked that are many questions and answers about working with lists of lists but i did not find any regarding this specific situation, so i would appreciate your help.

**Example of what I have:**

```
Records = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6,7], [8,9,10], [11], [12,13,14,15]]
```

And I want to eliminate the lists that have len inferior to 3. So at the end

**I want to have :**

```
Records = [[5,6,7], [8,9,10],[12,13,14,15]]
```

I think I have to do a loop to iterate trhough all the lists and check the len and after eliminate the ones that have `len > 3` but i have no idea how to code this. Can you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: *I've checked that are many questions and answers about working with lists of lists  but i did not find any regarding this specific situation* **IMPOSSIBLE**. This 
 tells you haven't tried anything.

Comment: I really tried ! I saw some similar cases but i did not know how to adapt them to my case, i'm new at this so maybe the answer was in front of me but I couldn't understand it. Sorry for the newbie question !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So naively, this would be something like

```py
result = []
for record in Records:         # iterate over each element of the list
    if len(record) >= 3:       # your filter requirement
        result.append(record)  # adding it to the results we want
print(result)
```

As in the other answers, you can compact the code quite a bit with a list comprehension, which has the structure

```py
[element for element in iterable if filter(element)]
```

In your case:

```py
[record for record in Records if len(record) >= 3]
```

Comment: Thanl you so much for your answer! It worked perfectly! Also thank you for the comments in the code, it helps a lot to understand what everything does. I started learning python recently and my knowledge about programming  is very limited, so once again thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
result = [record for record in records if len(record) >= 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

As easy as this:

```
Records = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6,7], [8,9,10], [11], [12,13,14,15]]

[i for i in Records if len(i)>=3]
```

Output:

```
[[5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```